# Assigning list elements to variable name in for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a following list of names:

```
names<-c('continent','city','country','carrier','asn','timezone','ip_routing','connection_type','linespeed','source_1')
```

I would like to use these names to assign them to string 'fraud_' at every iteration of the following for loop:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  
fraud_names[i]<-counter(fraud,colnames(fraud[i]))
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What is `counter` function

Comment: That is a function I created earlier. I am only concerned with assigning the above elements as a name at every iteration.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: `assign`+ `paste`?

Comment: Are you trying to create a column?

Comment: Suppose then:                                                                                           names<-c('continent','city','country','carrier','asn','timezone','ip_routing','connection_type','linespeed','source_1')

for (i in 1:10){
a_names[i]<-1
} I want to get

a_continent
a_city
a_country
a_carrier
etc. Seems like something along the lines of what Martin wrote.

Comment: @AlexVignjevic The last comment sounds like you want paste? See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to keep in a `list`

```
list1 <- setNames(rep(1, length(names)), names)
list2env(list1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not 100% clear what the end goal is, but based on your comment

> names<-c('continent','city','country','carrier','asn','timezone','ip_routing','connection_type','linespeed','source_1') ... I want to get a_continent a_city a_country a_carrier

The following may be helpful?

```
names <- c("continent", "city")
newnames <- paste0("a_", names)
newnames
[1] "a_continent" "a_city"
```

Having said that, maybe you are looking for:

```
names <- c("continent", "city")
fraud_names <- list() # better: vector(mode='list', length=length(names)) so as to preallocate the size.


for (i in names){ 
  fraud_names[paste0('fraud_', i)]<-1 
  } 

fraud_names
$fraud_continent
[1] 1

$fraud_city
[1] 1
```